# Is enumerate() or an explicit lookup more efficient?

Tags: python, performance, enumerate

I want to know which one more efficient between access a specific index or using `enumerate()` in looping. Say I have code like this:

```
myList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

# Get specific index
mySpecIndex = [i*myList[i] for i in range(len(myList))]

# Using enumerate
myEnumerate = [x*y for x, y in enumerate(myList)]

print(mySpecIndex)
print(myEnumerate)
```

Comment: If the difference between these matters at all, you're using Python for something where you should choose a language with a more efficient runtime (Go, Julia, etc) instead. Focus on readability and picking algorithms with good big-O characteristics, not microoptimizations *until and unless* a sampling profiler tells you that the code you're looking at is a bottleneck, and there aren't any places for improvement in algorithm selection.

Comment: The main reason for that advice is that any performance difference here is (1) a constant-factor difference, not a big-O one; and (2) implementation-defined, so prone to being completely different between different interpreter versions. Spending your time chasing improvements that could become completely moot or even counterproductive in the next version of the language is not a good use of resources.

Comment: That said, if you *really do* want to run an accurate microbenchmark, that's what the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) is for. No reason to ask a question here for something Python provides the tools to test yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll learn more in python